# What is the probability of all three events taking place on the same day?

Tags: probability, statistics

- The Melbourne cup takes place on the first Tuesday of November
- The US presidential election takes place every four years on the Tuesday following the first Monday in November
- Guy fawkes is on the 5th of november

The answer is 1/28. I understand that the probabilities of each independent event must be multiplied together but I’m not sure how to find out those probabilities.

I’m assuming that P(guy fawkes) is 1 and then trying to find the probabilty of the other events occurring on the 5th. I keep getting an outrageously small number, however. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't multiply unless you know they are independent or you are given the conditional probabilities.

Anyway, your question is poorly worded.  I'll take it to mean:

> What is the probability that, given a "random" year (after 1875 so both Melbourne Cup and US election exists, and Melbourne cup is on a Tuesday), that it is a US election year and all three are on the same date in Gregorian calendar, ignoring complexities such as international date line.

Then all three are on the same day in an US election year if and only if 5th of Novemeber is a Tuesday.

Since the Gregorian calendar has a period of 400 years (in that 400 years there are $400\times (7\times 52+1)+97$ days, this number is clearly divisible by 7 so we have the period), we calculate there are 13 years (see note) in any contiguous period of 400 years where the year is divisible by 4 and the 5th November of that year is a Tuesday.  So the answer is actually $\frac{13}{400}$, not $\frac1{28}$ as you suggested.

---

**Note**: In the years 1801--2200 inclusive, the 13 years are 1816, 1844, 1872, 1912, 1940, 1968, 1996, 2024, 2052, 2080, 2120, 2148 and 2176.

Comment: Agreed, and in fact that was a point that I made.  However, absent the assumptions that I made, how else can one reverse-engineer the answer of $(1/28)$?

Comment: There are two ways I can think of: (1) assume weekday is uniformly distributed in current (Gregorian) calendar, which of course is a logical fallacy and you can deduce anything from that; or (2) use Julian calendar, which arguably you could for Guy Fawkes day: at the time of the passing of [Observance of 5th November Act 1605](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observance_of_5th_November_Act_1605) in 1606 Britain was still on Julian calendar.

Comment: Gee, how many US presidential elections took place under the Julian Calendar?

Comment: Yes, that is stretching it a lot since Britain and its empire adopted Gregorian calendar in 1752.  But that is the only way I can think of to justify using $1/7$.

Comment: You have the issue backwards.  The question is whether there is a more likely explanation for using $(1/7)$ than simply laziness of the problem composer.

Answer (score -1):

Trick question.  Events 1,2, and 3 are not independent of each other.

If it is both presidential election year, and first tuesday following the first Monday is November 5th, (i.e. so it is both election day and Guy Fawkes day), then it has to be the 1st Tuesday in November (i.e. day of the Melbourne Cup).  This is because the previous Tuesday would have occurred in October.

I am reverse-engineering the answer as $a \times b$, where $a = (1/4) = $ chance of election year, and $b = (1/7) = $ chance that November 5th is Tuesday.

---

**Edit**
Actually, the answer that I offered is arguably inappropriate, because the question is *poorly worded*.  A better wording would be:

What is the probability that this year is an election year, and that sometime in November, all 3 events will occur on the same day?

---

**Edit**
Actually, even if you accept the re-wording offered above, it is still unclear (to me at least) how accurate the answer of $(1/28)$ is.

I am assuming that for each year that is divisible by $4$, the chance of November 5 being a Tuesday is $(1/7)$.  In my mind, the accuracy of this assumption is unclear and the question itself is ambiguous.  Is one supposed to check the data of November $5$, in the years $1900, 1904, \cdots, 2200$?

---

**Edit**
What is the chance that a specific day chosen at random is in an election year?  Ignoring the chance  that the year is divisible by $100$, there are $366$ days in an election year.

So the chance that a random day is occurring in an election year is **approximately**

$\displaystyle \frac{366}{366 + (3 \times 365)}.$

Comment: Arguably, due to the peculiarities of the Gregorian calendar (you have to look at November $5$ every $4th$ year in a $400$ year cycle) it is $\frac{13}{400} =0.0325$ rather than $\frac1{28} \approx 0.0357$

Comment: @Henry Agreed, and in fact that was a point that I made.  However, absent the assumptions that I made, how else can one reverse-engineer the answer of $(1/28)$?